# Как ускорить работу классификатора knn?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, классификация, sklearn, классификация-текста

Я делаю задание, где нужно написать свой аналог sklearn knn.
Вот основной код класса:

```
 def fit(self, X, y):
        self.X_train = X
        self.scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(self.X_train) 
        self.X_train_st = self.scaler.transform(self.X_train)
        self.y_train = y
        self.min_length = np.unique(self.y_train)[-1]+1
        
    def predict(self, X):
        self.X_test = X
        self.X_test_st = self.scaler.transform(self.X_test)
        self.y_pred = np.zeros(self.X_test_st.shape[0],dtype='int64')
        if(self.alg == 'brute'):
            dist = distance.cdist(self.X_test_st, self.X_train_st,  'minkowski', p=2.)
            ind = np.argsort(dist,axis=1)[:,:self.n]
            self.y_pred = np.argmax(np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.bincount(x, minlength=self.min_length), 1, self.y_train[ind]), axis=1)
        else:
            self.KDTree = KDTree(self.X_train_st)
            dist, ind = self.KDTree.query(self.X_test_st, k=self.n)
            self.y_pred = np.argmax(np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.bincount(x, minlength=self.min_length), 1, self.y_train[ind]), axis=1)
        return self.y_pred.ravel()
```

На всем известных ирисах работает достаточно быстро по сравнению с sklearn, но я хочу попробовать с fetch_20newsgroups и тут уже все плохо.
Сначала я использовала

```
vectorizer = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(max_df = 0.15, min_df=0.01)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
```

Попробовала посмотреть средний скор на кросс-валидации на трех фолдах, brute считается просто нереально долго, по сравнению с тем же sclearn, kdtree немного получше, но все равно очень долго.
TfidfVectorizer и cosine метрика помогают немного с точностью(хотя все равно очень низкая, около 15-17%), но что делать со скоростью я не знаю, особенно учитывая, что косинусную метрику использовать на кд дереве нельзя.

UPD: на pairwise_distances и без стандартизации все взлетело и по точности, и по скорости)

Comment: А вот это вообще что вычисляется: `self.min_length = np.unique(self.y_train)[-1]+1`? Просто интересно.

Comment: Я не понимаю - что именно вы так вычисляете. Тут берётся просто последний элемент из списка уникальных значений в `y_train` и прибавляется 1. В чём смысл этого действия? )

Comment: @CrazyElf я подумала, что minlength в bincount должен быть такой же, как максимальная метка класса, т.к. возвращается им массив с количеством вхождений индекса => индексы должны соответствовать классам => поэтому беру наибольшее из меток класса с помощью np.unique и прибавляю 1.
возможно, я что-то не так поняла)

Comment: `np.unique` выдаёт же просто список уникальных значений. Вам просто везёт и сначала попадаются нули, а потом единицы, а так то я так понимаю вам нужен `np.max` наверное? Просто это с виду что-то бессмысленное сейчас.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, он выдает упорядоченный список уникальных значений(по возрастанию) поэтому я беру с помощью [-1] последний элемент, который и будет максимальным, но вы правы, максимум было проще, я что-то здесь сглупила)

Comment: Хм, и правда sorted, вот я не знал, что `unique` возвращает сортированный список. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Но вы же понимаете, что в случае текста у вас получится как говорится 100500+ фич? И вам потом для всего этого хозяйства надо будет считать расстояния "каждый с каждым". Это реально долго. Тут может быть два выхода:

- Сильно ограничить число фич, при этом качество, которое у вас и так не очень, ещё упадёт.
- Использовать только методы, понимающие разреженные матрицы. Для этого нужно убрать `StandardScaler` (его в случае текстов обычно и не используют - нет смысла, плюс к тому он делает из разреженных матриц обычные) и постараться найти замену функции `distance.cdist`, такую же быструю (или ещё быстрее), но при этом понимающую разреженные матрицы. Что-нибудь вроде `NMSLIB` или [других подобных библиотек](https://github.com/erikbern/ann-benchmarks). Можно ещё попробовать вместо `CountVectorizer` использовать `HashingVectorizer`, ему не нужно хранить состояние, он поэтому должен по идее быстрее работать.

Простых путей тут нет, поскольку считать расстояния "каждый с каждым" для строк, в каждой из которых сотни тысяч фич - это никак не может быть быстрым. Вот в случае разреженной матрицы значимых фич у каждого сэмпла довольно немного и подсчёты расстояний идут гораздо быстрее.

Comment: да, фичей много, я поэтому ограничиваю по частотности - не беру сильно частные и слишком редкие, в итоге получается не такой высокий порядок фичей(но, конечно, падает сильно точность), однако считается слишком медленно, поэтому я подумала может есть какие то грубые недочеты в моем коде)

Comment: @София Код ваш я честно говоря не до конца понимаю, но с виду не должно тормозить особо - там кругом один `numpy` же. Основная проблема мне кажется всё-таки количество фич и то, что после `StandardScaler` разреженные матрицы фичей превращаются в обычные. Ну и `cdist` с разреженными матрицами тоже работать не умеет.